# Using Anvil with Jetpack compose - navigation with compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-2, jetpack-compose-navigation, anvil-di

I'm working on a new application, so we decided to work with compose and navigation with compose, but the deal is, we forced to use Anvil for DI,

**so my question is:** is there a better way to inject ViewModels within Composable context, other than using ViewModelProvider.Factory directly to retrieve ViewModel, with Anvil, please review the code example below:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.ProfileDestination(
    route: String,
    profileViewModelFactory: ProfileViewModelFactory, // e.g. passed from MainActivity
) {
        composable(route) {
            // this were my question is about.
            val profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
                it.viewModelStore,
                profileViewModelFactory
            )[ProfileViewModel::class.java]

            ProfileScreen(profileViewModel = profileViewModel)
        }
}
```

**Note:**
please note that, we will be working with pure compose with compose navigation (no fragments) just one MainActivity, so it would be a miss to just use this Activity as an EntryPoint for any VM factory we need to inject to use it to retrieve VM within composable context.

Comment: Most Commonly Used DI is ```Dagger-Hilt``` and ```Koin```. you can choose any of them for Dependecy injection. but without using DI you can also make use of ```ViewModel``` in pure Compose App Which I'm using is https://medium.com/@chiragthummar16/jetpack-compose-viewmodel-update-ui-using-flow-9ea7870a3072